# How can I get the OneToOne relationship easily?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two model, names User and Account,  the Account to User is one to one relationship:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True,blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField( max_length=11)   
    email_is_validated = models.BooleanField(default=False)   
    qq = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

class Account(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User)  
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)  
    total_charge = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)   
    total_consume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
```

So, in this case, in my serializer:

```
class OrderCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):

     def create(self, validated_data):

        request = self.context.get("request")
        if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
            user = request.user
```

I get the user, can I use user.account to get the account? 
and or whether I need to do something in User model, such as user @property. (those are my whimsical idea)
Or is there a convenient way to get the user's account instance?

Comment: *Can I use user.account to get the account?* Yes, that's how you do it.

Comment: Please set a proper title for your question which actually describes your problem in short.

Comment: Did you try this? Or I don't understand your problem, sorry.
`account = Account.objects.get(user=user)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set related_name for your model.

My code example:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, related_name='profiles')
    ...

class Project(models.Model):
    ...
```

Now I could call Projects from Profile using profile.projects.all()
And I could call Profiles from Project using project.profiles.all()

Docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name